# Showing that $X + Y$ and $X/Y$ are independent given that $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d with a PDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d with pdfs given by

$$f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases}
\text{exp}(-x), & \text{ if } x > 0, \\
0 & \text{ otherwise},
\end{cases} $$

and

$$f_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases}
\text{exp}(-y), & \text{ if } x > 0, \\
0 & \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases} $$

Show that $X + Y$ and $X/Y$ are independent.

---

**My attempt:**

By independence, we have

$$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\text{exp}(-(x + y)) & \text{ if } x+y > 0 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise.} 
\end{cases} $$

Let $Y_{1} = g_{1}(X, Y) = X + Y$ and $Y_{2} = g_{2}(X, Y) = X/Y$. Solving for $X$ and $Y$ gives us the solutions $X = Y_{1}Y_{2}/(Y_{2} + 1)$ and $Y = Y_{1}/(Y_{2} + 1)$. Thus, our Jacobian is given by

$$J = \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial X}\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial Y} - \frac{\partial g_{1}}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial g_{2}}{\partial X} $$

$$= -\frac{X + Y}{Y^{2}} $$

In terms of $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$, we have

$$-\frac{X + Y}{Y^{2}} = -\frac{(Y_{2} + 1)^{2}}{Y_{1}}.$$

Therefore, our new probability density function is given by

$$f_{Y_{1}, Y_{2}}(y_{1}, y_{2}) = f(x_{1}, x_{2}) \cdot |J|^{-1} $$

$$= \begin{cases} 
\dfrac{y_{1}}{(y_{2} + 1)^{2}} \cdot \text{exp}(-y_{1}) & \text{ if } y_{1} > 0 \\[1em]
0 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases} $$

So, we compute the marginal densities as follows:

$$f_{Y_{1}}(y_{1}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y_{1},Y_{2}}(y_{1}, y_{2}) \mathop{dy_{2}} = y_{1}\text{exp}(-y_{1}) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(y_{2} + 1)^{2}} \mathop{dy_{2}},$$

but the integral on the right diverges. Where did I go wrong? Can't figure it out. Also, did I do anything else wrong (in particular, are my domains for $f_{X, Y}$ and $f_{Y_{1}, Y_{2}}$ correct?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have if $y_1 > 0$, then

$$f_{Y_{1}}(y_{1}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y_{1},Y_{2}}(y_{1}, y_{2}) \mathop{dy_{2}} = y_{1}\text{exp}(-y_{1}) \cdot \int_{\color{red}0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(y_{2} + 1)^{2}} \mathop{dy_{2}} = y_1 \exp(-y_1)$$

Comment: Why is the lower bound $0$?

Comment: $y_2$ only take positive values right since it is a division of two positive numbers.

Comment: Ok. Then, $y_{1}$ must only take positive values too, right?

Comment: yes, addition of positive numbers.